# How can I put labels on buttons created from a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox

I am creating an elevator and have made some buttons from a JComboBox however I can't seem to get a label on them. There are up to 8 buttons created and the buttons have to be named from bottom to top. So the last button added should be floor one.

How can I make label on buttons that are created from the JComboBox?

```
[-------floor N-------]
[-------floor 3-------]
[-------floor 2-------]
[-------floor 1-------]
```

Here is some of my code...

```
//The main class
public class Elevator_Simulation extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public JLabel state; //The current state of the elevator being displayed
public ButtonPanel control; //The button control panel
private Elevator elevator; //The elevator area
String[] floorStrings = {"Select one", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};    
JComboBox floorList = new JComboBox(floorStrings); //The combo box
JButton go = new JButton();
public JPanel buttons;
//private int counter;

//constructor
public Elevator_Simulation() {        

    //Setting up layout and content pane
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));

    buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 1));
    add(buttons);

    //Panel creation
    JPanel centerpanel = new JPanel();
    centerpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Adds the button panel to the BorderLayout
    this.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);

    // adds the title to the top of p3
    p3.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // adds floorlist to the top right of p3
    p3.add(floorList, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // adds the start button to the panel
    p3.add(go, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    go.setText("Start");
    go.addActionListener(this);
    // adds p2 to the right of the container
    this.getContentPane().add(p3, BorderLayout.NORTH);

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Elevator_Simulation eSim = new Elevator_Simulation();
    eSim.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    eSim.setVisible(true);
}

//start of the actionPerformed
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int count = floorList.getSelectedIndex();
    //buttons.removeAll();
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        buttons.add(new JButton("F" + String.valueOf(index)));
    }
    buttons.revalidate();

    elevator = new Elevator(this);
    this.getContentPane().add(elevator, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
//end of the actionPerformed
```

Comment: Add the items to the combo box in the order you want them to appear

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the `floorStrings` so that the floors appear in the order you expect them to.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestComboBox08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestComboBox08();
    }

    public TestComboBox08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Select one", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"});

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(cb);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated with ability to simply reverse the selection indexing...**

So, now we've reversed the order, so we have reversed the selection index (item `8` is not at position `1`).

The simplest way I can see to fix this is to use `Arrays.asList(floorsList).indexOf(...)` which will return the location of the selected value in the `floorsList` array...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestComboBox08 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestComboBox08();
    }

    private String[] floorsList = new String[]{"Select one", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};

    public TestComboBox08() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(floorsList);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(cb);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String value = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                        int index = Arrays.asList(floorsList).indexOf(value);
                        System.out.println("Item at " + index + " = " + floorsList[index]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, that was strange. When I select "3" floors I get 6 buttons, and if I select "1" floor I get 8 buttons. The text on them is still the same, obviously. I think it returning the index of the array.

Comment: Yep, you're assuming the order of the values, which are now reversed, so `8` is not at position `1` and `1` is at position `9`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListCellRenderer` to manipulate the way an item is displayed in the combo box.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html

Edit:

Implement `ListCellRenderer` is a better way to say it

Comment: I don't care how it looks in the combo box. I am interested in the text displayed on the button that is created. After reading the ListCellRenderer API that is what I get from it. Am I right in saying that or have I completely misinterpreted it?

Comment: Looks like I misinterpreted the question. Try fixing the layout and button properties upon adding the buttons on the actionPerformed() method of the combo box. Also try calling buttons.pack() which will layout all components on the panel.